# Title of all my UIbuttons is written twice

Tags: ios, xcode6

Suddendly a strange problem appears in my app.
The title of all my buttons is written twice !
For instance, instead of "Menu", it is written "Menu Menu".

It appears only at runtime, on simulator and on real device. All is ok in my storyboard.
The buttons and their title are all created in my storyboard.
I have a button in navigationBar and 3 buttons per rows of tableView.
The title of all these buttons is written twice.
Here is a github image : 
 [buttonTitleRepeated.tiff](https://github.com/albajacq/pompier/blob/master/buttonTitleRepeated.tiff)
Here is the [scene description](https://github.com/albajacq/pompier/blob/master/ObjectifsRootVCScene.tiff) in storyboard.
After this problem occured, I downloaded last version of Xcode : 6.1.1, but my problem is still there.
Elsewhere in my code I create buttons programmatically, in this case, titles are not repeated.

Please, can you help ?**

Comment: You can add a link to an image, and show the code / describe the storyboard

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: Hi Wain, sorry but stackOverflow don't give me the right to post an image as I do not have 10 reputations.

Comment: My storyboard contains a UIbutton in the navigation bar.

Comment: It contains also 3 buttons in each cell of a tableView. In all these buttons the title is written two times

Comment: How can I send you an image ?

Comment: This appears only at runtime, on simulator and on real device. All is ok in my storyboard.
The buttons and their title are all created in my storyboard.
I have a button in navigationBar and 3 buttons per rows of tableView.
The title of all these buttons is written twice.
Here is a github image : https://github.com/albajacq/pompier/blob/f7d87bb006051f6fce9b15ce2a97837f7b14e248/buttonTitleRepeated.tiff
 
After this problem occured, I downloaded last version of Xcode : 6.1.1, but my problem is still there.
 
Please, can you help ?

Comment: It is not a button Navigation bar button issue right ? have you set title for bar button programatically ? Can you share your code related to this ?

Comment: Hi Vineesh, these titles are set in storyboard, no code to share. I added another image showing storyboard description.